# Typing effect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to create a webPage whereby most of the text is typed on the screen as if the page is typing to the reader in real time. Thus far, I've come up with this code, and it gets the words on screen, but it does not do so in a typed effect manner.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Murder on the Menu</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color:#222222;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        #typed{
            color:red;
            font-size:150%;
            float:left;
        }
        .cursor{
            height:24px;
            width:2px;
            background:lawngreen;
            float:left;
            opacity:0;
            animation:blink 0.75s linear infinite alternate;

        }
        @keyframes blink{
            50% {
                opacity:0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity:1;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="typed"></div>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            var txt='Murder on the Menu: a production by Brendan Lewis.';
            var speed=500;
            var identifier;
            function addLetter(word){
                document.getElementById(word).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
            }
           for(i=0;i<txt.length;i++){
               setInterval(addLetter("typed"),speed);
           }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things that are going wrong in your example is that for each letter in txt you start a new interval without ever stopping the interval, this creates a memory leak.

What's actually happening that causes your txt to visually be printed all at once is that by passing `addLetter` to the interval like this: `setInterval(addLetter("typed"),speed);` you actually **invoke** the function before ever it gets passed into the interval. In reality, the `txt` is printed in the speed of your `for loop`.

What you need to do is pass an anonymous function that invokes `addLetter` with the right parameters, see answer.

Solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var i=0;
   var txt='Murder on the Menu: a production by Brendan Lewis.';
   var speed=500;
   var identifier;
   var interval = setInterval(function() { 
      return addLetter("typed")
   }, speed);

   function addLetter(word){
     document.getElementById(word).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
     if (i < txt.length) i++;
     else clearInterval(interval)
   }

</script>
```